# After opening a .doc/.docx, I would like to save the converted .pages in same folder as .doc was opened. Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

Tags: macos, finder, ms-office, numbers, pages

This drives me crazy. What I usually do is drag the original folder location temporarily into the Finder Sidebar so I'm quickly able to find it in the save dialog.  Hopefully there is a setting or other technique I've missed all these years.  Same for Excel and Numbers of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want a tool for this like default folder.

- https://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/

If you’re into automation, [scripting this is possible](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/376138/5472), but may not be your ideal solution. Default folder has [helped with this for all apps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/16010/5472) for decades whereas scripts are specific to each app.